# Determining the exact cause of CL_INVALID_GL_SHAREGROUP_REFERENCE_KHR

Tags: debugging, opengl, runtime-error, interop, opencl

While attempting to perform OpenGL + OpenCL interop, I get an error return code `CL_INVALID_GL_SHAREGROUP_REFERENCE_KHR` when calling `cl::CommandQueue::enqueueNDRangeKernel()` (using the official C++ wrapper for OpenCL).

According to the [official OpenCL 1.2 documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateContext.html), this error code can mean a host of different things (copied verbatim):

> 1. `CL_INVALID_GL_SHAREGROUP_REFERENCE_KHR` when an invalid OpenGL context or share group object handle is specified in properties (only
>      if the `cl_khr_gl_sharing` extension is enabled).
> 2. `CL_INVALID_GL_SHAREGROUP_REFERENCE_KHR` if no OpenGL or OpenGL ES context or share group is specified in the attribute list given to
>      clCreateContext and any of the commands in section 9.7 are called. (if
>      the `cl_khr_gl_sharing` extension is enabled)
> 3. `CL_INVALID_GL_SHAREGROUP_REFERENCE_KHR` if the `cl_khr_gl_sharing` extension is enabled and if a context was specified by any of the
>      following means:
>
>    - A context specified for an EGL-based OpenGL ES or OpenGL
>        implementation by setting the attributes `CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR` and
>        `CL_EGL_DISPLAY_KHR`.
>    - A context was specified for a GLX-based
>        OpenGL implementation by setting the attributes `CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR`
>        and `CL_GLX_DISPLAY_KHR`.
>    - A context was specified for a WGL-based
>        OpenGL implementation by setting the attributes `CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR`
>        and `CL_WGL_HDC_KHR`.
>
>    and any of the following conditions hold:
>
>    - The specified display and context attributes do not identify a valid OpenGL or OpenGL ES context.
>    - The specified context does not support buffer and renderbuffer objects.
>    - The specified context is not compatible with the OpenCL context being created (for example, it exists in a physically distinct address space, such as another hardware device, or does not support sharing data with OpenCL due to implementation restrictions).
> 4. `CL_INVALID_GL_SHAREGROUP_REFERENCE_KHR` if a share group was specified for a CGL-based OpenGL implementation by setting the
>      attribute CL_CGL_SHAREGROUP_KHR, and the specified share group does
>      not identify a valid CGL share group object (if the
>      `cl_khr_gl_sharing` extension is enabled).

In my case, I am on Ubuntu Linux which uses GLX, and I have carefully prepared my OpenCL context with the `CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR` + `CL_GLX_DISPLAY_KHR` options. I have also checked my devices to make sure they all support the `cl_khr_gl_sharing` extension.

I have also carefully set up the initial OpenGL context to be as OpenCL friendly as possible.

I still get this error. What I am asking now is, given this situation, **how can I trace the actual cause of this return code**?

Is there some way to figure out which of the 7+ possible reasons that causes it in my case?

Comment: I have not seen any way of getting more detailed information (then there would be separate status codes for the different cases?). I got this error as well, and it was due to the OpenGL context being incompatible with the requested OpenCL context, where I had a direct rendering GL context but tried to create a CL context on the GPU. This corresponds to the 3.3 situation in the reference. The solution was to install GPU drivers with OpenGL support. Although this does not answer the question, it solves one of the causes.

Comment: This error sometimes popup if you forget to acquire/release GL objects around the kernel run with enqueueAcquireGLObjects/enqueueReleaseGLObjects.