# Invalid share group error when trying to create OpenCL context from OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, opencl

I am getting `CL_INVALID_GL_SHAREGROUP_REFERENCE_KHR` (error -1000) from `clCreateContext(...)` in my Windows application which has OpenGL window already initialized.

The code is:

```
cl_platform_id platforms[4];
cl_uint numOfPlatforms;

clGetPlatformIDs(4, platforms, &numOfPlatforms);

cl_context_properties props[] =
{
    CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentContext(),
    CL_WGL_HDC_KHR, (cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentDC(),
    CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)(platforms[0]),
    0
};

cl_device_id devices[4];
cl_uint numOfDevices;

clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 4, devices, &numOfDevices);

cl_int createContextError;
auto clContext = clCreateContext(props, 1, devices, &pfn_notify, NULL, &createContextError);
```

I have checked extensions of current device and it does support `cl_khr_gl_sharing`.

Spec:

```
CPU:        AMD ThreadRipper 3960x
GPU:        Nvidia RTX2080s
OpenCL SDK: Khronos
```

Comment: Did you check the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42709957/18667225 ?

Comment: @Markus Yes, but it didn't help me much. I would need to know what I am doing wrong or what to check.

Comment: Can you try to reduce your problem to a minimal but complete reproducible example? Please add information about your cpu and your compiler.

Comment: @Markus I am using AMD Threadripper 3960x with nVidia RTX2080S. And this is minimal example.  I need `createContextError` to be zero not -1000. Compiler is some default of Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: @JaSHin The example is not reproducible in that that we can't copy it and compile it. See [mre].

Comment: Which OpenCL SDK do you use?

Comment: @Markus Khronos

Answer (score 2):

This standalone executable works on my laptop. Please check its output on your environent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <CL/opencl.h>


void CL_CALLBACK pfn_notify(const char *errinfo, const void *private_info, size_t cb, void *user_data) {
    fprintf(stderr, "OpenCL Error (via pfn_notify): %s\n", errinfo);
}

int main() {
    cl_platform_id platforms[4];
    cl_uint numOfPlatforms;
    char device_info[4096];
    char * found;
    
    clGetPlatformIDs(4, platforms, &numOfPlatforms);

    cl_context_properties props[] = {
        CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentContext(),
        CL_WGL_HDC_KHR, (cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentDC(),
        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)(platforms[0]),
        0
    };

    cl_device_id devices[4];
    cl_uint numOfDevices;

    clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 4, devices, &numOfDevices);

    clGetDeviceInfo(devices[0], CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS, sizeof(device_info), device_info, NULL);
    found = strstr(device_info, "cl_khr_gl_sharing");

    if (found) fprintf(stdout, "cl_khr_gl_sharing supported\n");
        
    cl_int createContextError;
    auto clContext = clCreateContext(props, 1, devices, &pfn_notify, NULL, &createContextError);
    
    fprintf(stdout, "Context: %p\n", clContext);
}
```

Output:

```
cl_khr_gl_sharing supported
Context: 0000022C7B2E5E70
```

Spec:

```
CPU/GPU:    i5
OpenCL SDK: Khronos
```